# C# List<string> to string with delimiter

Tags: c#, string, list, delimiter

Is there a function in C# to quickly convert some collection to string and separate values with delimiter?

For example:

`List<string> names` --> `string names_together = "John, Anna, Monica"`

Answer (score 1699, accepted):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).  If you have a `List<string>` then you can call [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) first:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "John", "Anna", "Monica" };
var result = String.Join(", ", names.ToArray());
```

In .NET 4 you don't need the `ToArray` anymore, since there is an overload of `String.Join` that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`.

In newer versions of .NET different `String.Join` overloads use different approaches to produce the result. And this might affect the performance of your code.

For example, those that accept `IEnumerable` use `StringBuilder` under the hood. And the one that accepts an array uses a heavily optimized implementation with arrays and pointers.

### **Results:**

> John, Anna, Monica

Comment: `string.Join` (lowercase `string`) is preferable over the uppercase because it saves you from having to add `using System;` at the top of the file in some cases.

Answer (score 139):

You can also do this with linq if you'd like

```
var names = new List<string>() { "John", "Anna", "Monica" };
var joinedNames = names.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```

Although I prefer the non-linq syntax in Quartermeister's answer and I think `Aggregate` might perform slower (probably more string concatenation operations).

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies, both works fine. You're right I did a small performance measurement using Stopwatch class and the linq-way is much slower:  String.Join(", ", names.ToArray());   --> took 18 ticks
Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b) --> took 736 ticks

Comment: Yeah I think `Aggregate` is better for Math type operations. With strings this operation it is similar to `for each` ing and just appending to a string which is very slow in inefficient because you are creating a new string for each item that exists in the list.

Comment: Note that Aggregate without a seed value will throw an InvalidOperationException if the container is empty. Use the seeded version Aggregate(seed, func) to avoid error handling code or conditional checks. String.Join does not throw on empty so no seed or extra code is required... plus it doesn't require Linq and the syntax is a little clearer.

Comment: Aggregate in the example above may work faster if you'll use StringBuilder. Using '+' to perform multiple concatenation is not recommended.

See Remarks section in here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've found that `StringBuilder.AppendJoin()` looks like exactly what the op need:
`var names = new List<string>() { "John", "Anna", "Monica" }; string joinedNames = new StringBuilder().AppendJoin(", ", names);`
It's roughly same as `string.Join()`, I've not preformance-tested this.

In case you desperately need a Linq form, without aggregation:
`var names = new List<string>() { "John", "Anna", "Monica" }; var joinedNames = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); names.ForEach(a => joinedNames.Append((joinedNames.Length > 0 ?", " : "") + a)); //joinedNames.ToString();`

Answer (score 5):

An extension method based on the accepted answer, that I use in all my projects:

```
public static string StringJoin(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, values);
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = names.StringJoin(", ");
```

P.S. Don't ever use `Aggregate` for this, it is *two orders of magnitude slower* than `string.Join`