# Coalescing in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have these code :

```
var result = new Collection<object>();

result.Add(list.Select(s => new
               {
                   s.ID,
                   s.Users
               })
           );
```

Users is a collection which means it can contains multiple names for example `"John", "Rick", "Tom"`, etc. I want to coalsescing it into one `string` `"John, Rick, Tom"`. Any idea how to achieve this result?

Thank you

UPDATE :

Answer

```
var result = new Collection<object>();

result.Add(list.Select(s => new
               {
                   s.ID,
                   Users = string.Join(",", s.Users)
               })
           );
```

Comment: `string.Join(",", result)`?

Comment: `result` is a collection of object, is it possible to do it inside LINQ `select` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from your code, it's easier to just go to

```
result.Add(list.Select(s => new
                {s.ID, string.Join(",",s.Users)}));
```

That should return you a list of pairs with ID, and joined strings of users delimited by ",".

Comment: Already tried this and gave me error `"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."`

Comment: NVM I fixed it by changing `string.Join(",", s.Users)` to `Users = string.Join(",", s.Users)`. Will mark as answer in 4 mins

Answer (score 0):

If Users is a List, you can use the following code:

```
var result = new Collection<object>();

result.Add(list.Select(s => new
               {
                   s.ID,
                   string.Join(",", s.Users.ToArray())   
               })
           );
```

Also, you can check this similar question :[C# List to string with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575029/c-sharp-liststring-to-string-with-delimiter)