# List<string> returns System.String[] instead of the actual text

Tags: c#, string, list, parsing, logfile

Here is what I am actually trying to do, I am trying to use lists and classes instead of the way it is now to do the same thing:

```
public ActionResult Testcsvbp()
    {
        string Workingfolder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Files");
        string FileNamer = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
        ViewBag.Output = "No Test Data Available...........";
        ViewBag.Details = "No Details Avalable...........";

        // Output the start time.
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        ViewBag.Output = "Program Start Time: " + startTime.ToString("T");

        // Read all log file lines into an array.           
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Workingfolder + @"/access.log");

        // Build a data table for all the lines we decide to keep.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(long));
        dt.Columns.Add("IP_Address", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("IP_Address_Integer", typeof(long));


        // Make the IP_Address Column a primary key to speed up the process of searching the data table over and over.
        // Note: the DataTable type does not have the capability to be indexed.
        dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["IP_Address"] };


        // Iterate over the lines array.  Since this iteration will be expensive, we want to hunt out bad lines and append the good lines into a dataTable.
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {

            // Create array for that line, splitting fields by sspaces.  From this point, much of our conditional logic will be specific array indexes.
            // This assumes that this program is only for schema used in the logs/access.log file.
            string[] lineArray = lines[i].Split(' ');

            // We don't want to use comment lines or data within the comment lines.  To avoid this, we'll assume a length of 21 items for lines[i].
            if (lines[i].Substring(0, 1) != "#" && lineArray.Length == 21)
            {

                // Isolate lines where the request was a GET protocol on port 80. Also eliminate IPs starting with 207.114 .
                if (lineArray[7] == "80" && lineArray[8] == "GET" && lineArray[2].Substring(0, 7) != "207.114")
                {


                    // Create datarow to add to data table container.
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Count"] = 1;
                    dr["IP_Address"] = lineArray[2];
                    dr["IP_Address_Integer"] = IPtoInt(lineArray[2]);

                    // Create duplicate search expression and check for duplicates.
                    string searchExpression = "IP_Address = '" + lineArray[2].ToString() + "'";
                    DataRow[] duplicateRow = dt.Select(searchExpression);

                    // Prevent duplicate rows for an IP address.  If a duplicate is fount, add 1 to the "Count" row.  Else, add the row.                    
                    if (duplicateRow.Length > 0)
                    {
                        int duplicateIndex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(duplicateRow[0]);
                        dt.Rows[duplicateIndex]["Count"] = int.Parse(dt.Rows[duplicateIndex]["Count"].ToString()) + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }

                    // Have the data table accept all changes.
                    dt.AcceptChanges();

                }
            }
        }

        // Now sort the datatable by the IP Address integer representation.
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "Count desc, IP_Address_Integer desc";
        dt = dv.ToTable();

        // Create a string builder to contain the CSV file contents.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Add column names as the first line.
        sb.Append("Count,IP_Address");

        // Add the data to subsequent lines
        ViewBag.Output = ""; //
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var fields = row["Count"] + ",\"" + row["IP_Address"] + "\"\n";
            var columns = row["Count"] + ",\"" + row["IP_Address"] + "<br>";//mbelcher
            sb.AppendLine(fields);
            ViewBag.Output += columns; //
        }

        // Write the CSV file to the file system.
        string SaveFilePath = Workingfolder + @"\IPaddressComplete" + FileNamer + ".csv";
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(SaveFilePath))
         {
            sw.Write(sb.ToString());
            ViewBag.Details = sb.ToString();//
            ViewBag.FileNamer = SaveFilePath;
        }

        ViewBag.LinkToFile = "<a target='_blank' href='http://logparser.lol.com/files/" + @"IPaddressComplete" + FileNamer + ".csv'>Download File</a>";

        // Output the start time.
        TimeSpan duration = endTime - startTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Program Duration: " + duration.Seconds.ToString() + " seconds");
        return View("Testcsvbp");
    }
```

IIS LOG FILE line sample:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 5.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2010-08-12 00:00:01
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-sitename s-computername s-ip s-port     cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken cs-version cs-host cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) 

2010-08-12 00:00:01 69.143.116.98 - W3SVC106 STREAM 207.22.66.152 80 GET /includes/scripts.js - 200 0 2258 381 94 HTTP/1.1 www.lol.com Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+WOW64;+GoogleT5;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+Media+Center+PC+5.0;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30618;+.NET4.0C) - http://www.lol.com/
```

I started with writing the below code, all I am getting in the view is this:

1. System.String[]
2. System.String[]

I am probably missing something but now really sure how to accomplish what I want with lists and classes.

```
        // List to contain rows we are going to use.
    List<LogParserModel> LogListParsed = new List<LogParserModel>();

    var logFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Workingfolder +     @"/accessShort.log");
    List<string> LogList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var s in logFile) LogList.Add(s);
    var LogListCount = LogList.Count();
    ViewBag.LogListCount = LogListCount;

    // This will go through each line of the log file that was loaded into list LogList
    // 1. We split this by spaces to delemite values.
    string LineItemCheck = "";
    int LineItemCount = 0;

    //for (var m = 0; m < LogList.Count; m++)
    foreach (string line in LogList)
    {
        LineItemCount++;
        //Split on space - need to do this then turn back into alist?
        LineItemCheck = line;//          LogList.ToString();
        LineItemCheck = LineItemCheck.Split(' ').ToString();
        if (LineItemCheck.Substring(0, 1) == "#")
        {
            // we remove this line from the collection.
            ViewBag.RemovedLines += "(" + LineItemCount + ")" + LineItemCheck + "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            //process it and add to the final "List<LogParser> LogListParsed"
            ViewBag.AddedLines += "(" + LineItemCount + ")" + LineItemCheck.ToString() + "<br>";
        }
    }
    ViewBag.LASTLineItemChecked = LineItemCheck;
    ViewBag.TotalLinesProcessed = LineItemCount.ToString();
    return View("Testcsv");     
}
```

Here are the classes I made; nothing in them at all yet:

```
    public class LogParserModel
{
    public long HostCount { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public long IPfilter { get; set; }
}
```

Below was to do the parsing with methods.

```
    public class LogParser
{
    //Method to return something here

    //Method to return something here

    public string[] GetParsedList(string[] SomeArray)
    {
        return SomeArray.ToArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is 'below code'?

Comment: Indenting code sometimes helps

Comment: Firstly, please indent code - it makes it much more readable if you need help, secondly it looks as if you misunderstand the function of `String.Split(' ')`, your variable `string LineItemCheck = "";` will not display what you want with this `LineItemCheck = LineItemCheck.Split(' ').ToString();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List<string> to string with delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575029/c-sharp-liststring-to-string-with-delimiter)

Comment: I think here the line `LineItemCheck = LineItemCheck.Split(' ').ToString();` not required any how.
you are using `.Substring(0, 1)` which will not let that line get affect.

Comment: Why do you need to do the `String.Split()` in the first place?

Comment: I didn't put enough information before so I updated it with that and what I have already done.

Answer (score 2):

In `LineItemCheck = LineItemCheck.Split(' ').ToString();` part you've splitting string, and it returns an array. So if you `ToString()` it, it will return the type of your array/list.

Comment: This is the problem of his code, but how this is a solution ? What he should do ?

Comment: The solution is to check his code logic in that part.

Comment: I didn't put enough information before so I updated it with that and what I have already done.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
foreach (string line in LogList)
        {
            LineItemCount++;
            //Split on space - need to do this then turn back into alist?
            string LineItem = LineItemCheck = line;

        if (LineItem.Substring(0, 1) == "#")
        {
            // we remove this line from the collection.
            ViewBag.RemovedLines += "(" + LineItemCount + ")" + LineItemCheck + "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            //process it and add to the final "List<LogParser> LogListParsed"
            ViewBag.AddedLines += "(" + LineItemCount + ")" + LineItemCheck.ToString() + "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't put enough information before so I updated it with that and what I have already done.