# Write list/array on a single line

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to output my lists and arrays in the middle of the sentence all in one line with commas separating each element.
For example, dblList which contains 22.3, 44.5, 88.1 I need the output to look like this, "For the list (22.3, 44.5, 88.1), the average of its elements is: average."

I'm sure it's really easy to do but I can't figure it out.

Any help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Averages
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> integerList1 = new List<int> { 3 };
            List<int> integerList2 = new List<int> { 12, 15 };
            List<double> dblList = new List<double> { 22.3, 44.5, 88.1 };
            int[] myArr = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            CalculateAverage(integerList1, integerList2, dblList, myArr);
        }

        private static void CalculateAverage(List<int> intlist1, List<int> intlist2, List<double> dblist, int[] myArr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"For the list ({intlist1}), the average of its elements is: {intlist1.Average():F}");
            Console.WriteLine($"For the list ({intlist2}), the average of its elements is: {intlist2.Average():F}");
            Console.WriteLine($"For the list ({dblist}), the average of its elements is: {dblist.Average():F}");
            Console.WriteLine($"For the array [{myArr}], the average of its elements is: {myArr.Average():F}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List<string> to string with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575029/c-sharp-liststring-to-string-with-delimiter)

Comment: string output = string.Format("({0})", string.Join(",",dblList.Select(x => x.ToString())));

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `string.Join`:

```
List<double> dblList = new List<double> { 22.3, 44.5, 88.1 };

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Here's the list: ({0}).", string.Join(", ", dblList)));

// Output: Here's the list: (22.3, 44.5, 88.1).
```