# List of string separate with comma and add prefix string to every item of list

Tags: c#, string, list

I have list like...

```
List[0] = "Banana"
List[1] = "Apple"
List[2] = "Orange"
```

I want to produce output as `"My-Banana,My-Apple,My-Orange"` for that I'm using the following code:

```
string AnyName = string.Join(",", Prefix + List));
```

But not getting the expected output, how to add **My-** before every item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# List<string> to string with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575029/c-sharp-liststring-to-string-with-delimiter)

Comment: `string.Join(",", List.Select(x => $"My-{x}"))`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xvu2mV):

```
listInput[0] = "Apple";
listInput[1] = "Banana";
listInput[2] = "Orange";
string Prefix = "My-";         
string strOutput = string.Join(",", listInput.Select(x=> Prefix + x));
Console.WriteLine(strOutput);
```

And you will get the output as `My-Apple,My-Banana,My-Orange`

Comment: yeah Thanks Exactly  what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

First you would want to add the prefix to each element in `List` like so.

```
for (var i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
    List[i] = "My-" + List[i];
```

Then you would want to split `List` with commas like this.

`var AnyName = String.Join(",", List);`