# Join to element of a list in one element with C#

Tags: c#

I want to join two different sentences in one sentence:

```
 var list1 = new List<string>();
  list1.Add("Hello ");
  list1.Add("my name is John");
```

when I print elements of this list:

```
foreach (var item in list1)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(item);
           }
```

**Output:**

```
Hello 

my name is John
```

What I want to get is:

`Hello my name is John`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concat all strings inside a List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575029/c-sharp-liststring-to-string-with-delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the name of the method is [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0):

```
string joined = string.Join(" ", list1);
```

You don't need that trailing space after "Hello ".

However, in this case you could also have used `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`.